# How to install poppler correctly for pdftotext

Tags: docker-compose, pdftotext, poppler

When I try to build my docker-compose pdftotext seems to fail with this error:

```
Running setup.py install for pdftotext: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ihm5qxa9/pdftotext/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ihm5qxa9/pdftotext/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-wa_n7pgk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ihm5qxa9/pdftotext/
Complete output (14 lines):
WARNING: pkg-config not found--guessing at poppler version.
         If the build fails, install pkg-config and try again.
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pdftotext' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=1 -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pdftotext.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pdftotext.o -Wall
pdftotext.cpp:3:10: fatal error: poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h: No such file or directory
 #include <poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tested this on windows and linux with the same error. Has anyone found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is hard to help without knowing the content of your docker-compose/Dockerfile. But as mentioned in the error message, you are missing pkg-config. You should try to run `apt-get install pkg-config`.

You can also check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272431/installing-poppler-utils-of-version-0-82-in-docker/63265495#63265495) about how to use the latest version of the [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) in the Docker.