# Installing Poppler utils of version 0.82 in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, poppler

Below is the dockerfile that I am using

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
RUN apt update
RUN apt install poppler-utils -y
RUN apt install git -y
WORKDIR /src/
ADD . /src
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

when I check the version of poppler using pdftocairo -v , I get 0.71 as the poppler version. I need to install specific version(0.82) of poppler with a python baseimage

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing this answer, the latest version of the [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) is 20.08.0. If you want to use this version in your Docker image, you can do it as follows:

1. Create a Dockerfile with the following content

   ```
   FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget build-essential cmake libfreetype6-dev pkg-config libfontconfig-dev libjpeg-dev libopenjp2-7-dev -y
   RUN wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-data-0.4.9.tar.gz \
       && tar -xf poppler-data-0.4.9.tar.gz \
       && cd poppler-data-0.4.9 \
       && make install \
       && cd .. \
       && wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-20.08.0.tar.xz \
       && tar -xf poppler-20.08.0.tar.xz \
       && cd poppler-20.08.0 \
       && mkdir build \
       && cd build \
       && cmake .. \
       && make \
       && make install \
       && ldconfig
   CMD tail -f /dev/null
   ```
2. Build and run your image

   ```
   docker build -t milanhlinak/poppler .
   docker run --name poppler milanhlinak/poppler
   ```
3. Verify that Poppler was installed

   ```
   PS C:\Users\Milan\poppler-docker> docker exec -it poppler pdftotext -v
   pdftotext version 20.08.0
   Copyright 2005-2020 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
   Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
   ```

You can also check https://hub.docker.com/r/milanhlinak/poppler/

Comment: How would I make it a static build binary? I just need pdfinfo to run in AWS labmda.

Comment: Many thanks. This worked great trying to run the latest version of poppler on Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Milan's response and updating it with the latest versions of poppler. Also adding support for pdftocairo and ability to output as tiff.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install apt-utils wget build-essential cmake libfreetype6-dev pkg-config libfontconfig-dev libjpeg-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libcairo2-dev libtiff5-dev -y
RUN wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-data-0.4.10.tar.gz \
    && tar -xf poppler-data-0.4.10.tar.gz \
    && cd poppler-data-0.4.10 \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-21.03.0.tar.xz \
    && tar -xf poppler-21.03.0.tar.xz \
    && cd poppler-21.03.0 \
    && mkdir build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake .. \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd ../.. \
    && ldconfig \
    && rm poppler-data-0.4.10.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf poppler-data-0.4.10 \
    && rm poppler-21.03.0.tar.xz \
    && rm -rf poppler-21.03.0
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```