# CMake 3.18.0 not finding libopenjpeg2

Tags: cmake, centos7, poppler, openjpeg

Please forgive my ignorance when is comes to Cmake. I'm trying to install Poppler 0.86.1 on Centos 7 but I am stuck with an error that says `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:208 (message): Install libopenjpeg2 before trying to build poppler.` **I have installed libopenjpeg2 including the dev package by running the following:**

`sudo yum install openjpeg2-devel`

I am taking the following steps to install poppler:

```
wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.86.1.tar.xz
tar xf poppler-0.86.1.tar.xz
cd poppler-0.86.1/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Which results in the following error

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:208 (message):
 Install libopenjpeg2 before trying to build poppler.  You can also decide
 to use the internal unmaintained JPX decoder or none at all.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

This is where the failure occurs in the CMakeLists.txt

```
if(ENABLE_LIBOPENJPEG STREQUAL "openjpeg2")
  find_package(OpenJPEG)
  set(WITH_OPENJPEG ${OpenJPEG_FOUND})
  if(NOT OpenJPEG_FOUND OR OPENJPEG_MAJOR_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Install libopenjpeg2 before trying to build poppler. You can also decide to use the internal unmaintained JPX decoder or none at all.")
  endif()
  ...
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction in figuring out how to get Poppler 0.86.1 to successfully install on Centos 7?

Comment: Are you sure CentOS is packaging the correct CMake package file.  Otherwise reverse this commit.
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/commit/12bf632489587df9da416ed8303fb8aefc26bdac

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, I had the same problem when I was trying to use the latest version of the Poppler in my Docker image. I fixed it by installing `libopenjp2-7-dev`. Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272431/installing-poppler-utils-of-version-0-82-in-docker/63265495#63265495), specifically, the second row of my Dockerfile where you can see what I installed before running `cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this and it was due to https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/issues/1174.  I modified my local copy of `/lib64/openjpeg-2.3/OpenJPEGConfig.cmake` to work around this.