# How to update dockerfile to update version of popper-utils' pdftotext?

Tags: docker, debian, poppler-utils

I currently have a project I'm working on where the version of pdftotext from poppler-utils is using the "testing" version (found here https://manpages.debian.org/testing/poppler-utils/pdftotext.1.en.html).  Instead, I want to use the version "experimental" by updating the debian image in the dockerfile (trying to avoid conflicts with other items).  Is there a simple way to do this or is this not feasible?

Comment: I'm thinking of doing something like this:

`RUN apt-get remove poppler-utils`
`RUN apt-get install poppler-utils=22.08.0-1`


Basically, I would be removing the existing poppler-utils package, then adding one in that has the version of pdftotext that I would want.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, I figured out the solution.  I got some data from this post that provided some good insight on the commands.  I had to update to the version that would work with my bot base but got it all figured out.
[Installing Poppler utils of version 0.82 in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272431/installing-poppler-utils-of-version-0-82-in-docker)

Leaving this here in case someone else encounters something similar.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget build-essential cmake libfreetype6-dev 
pkg-config libfontconfig-dev libjpeg-dev libopenjp2-7-dev -y
RUN wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-data-0.4.9.tar.gz \
    && tar -xf poppler-data-0.4.9.tar.gz \
    && cd poppler-data-0.4.9 \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-20.08.0.tar.xz \
    && tar -xf poppler-20.08.0.tar.xz \
    && cd poppler-20.08.0 \
    && mkdir build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake .. \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && ldconfig
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```